# libmicrohttpd: undefined reference to `pthread_setname_np@GLIBC_2.12' when linking

Tags: linker, arm, shared-libraries, glibc, ldd

I am using libmicrohttpd 0.9.53 in my project and decided to update it to the latest version (0.9.71). I am cross-compiling for ARM and this is the output of `arm-linux-gcc --version`:

```
arm-linux-gcc (4.4.4_09.06.2010) 4.4.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and the output of `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6`:

```
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u3) stable release version 2.19, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.4.
Compiled on a Linux 3.16.7 system on 2016-02-12.
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

The compilation is successful, however, I get these errors when linking with the shared library:

```
arm-linux-gcc     -Llib/libmicrohttpd/lib -Wl,-rpath,./lib   -o "proj" build/src/proj.o -lpthread -lm -lmicrohttpd
lib/libmicrohttpd/lib/libmicrohttpd.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setname_np@GLIBC_2.12'
lib/libmicrohttpd/lib/libmicrohttpd.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:191: proj] Error 1
```

On the target machine, I ran `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 | grep clock_gettime`:

```
782: 000e48e4   116 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __clock_gettime@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
1625: 000e48e4   116 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   12 clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.17
```

And `readelf -Ws /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 | grep pthread_setname` gives no result.

Apparently, the two symbols mentioned in the error have been added between the old and new releases and it seems like my current version of libc does not define them.
Am I completely off track here? Do I have to somehow update libc? Could you please suggest anything that could point me to the right direction?

Comment: Complete speculation: this might be an issue with the order of your flags. Try: `-lm -lmicrohttpd -lpthread`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your toolchain defaults `-Wl,--as-needed`. In this case, link order matters even for shared objects.

Try replacing `-lpthread -lm -lmicrohttpd` with this:

```
-lm -lmicrohttpd -lpthread
```

The `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17` problem requires a rebuild with the version of glibc in your cross-build environment. It seems it was compiled on the target system (which has glibc 2.19, per your question), but it could have been built against any version that has `clock_gettime` in `libc.so.6`, starting with glibc 2.17. Your cross-compilation environment has a glibc version prior to that change (so glibc 2.16 or earlier), so it does not recognize the `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17` symbol version.